# Responsive image folder creation inconsistencies

Tags: media

Just implementing responsive images and find that I have one content type (slider) that the folder structure does not get created as expected in the styles folder.

Output is:

slider_mobile1
| ---public
| ---core
| ---modules
| ---image
| sample.png

Now on all the other content types there are no issues:

mobile_x1_banner
| ---public
| ---banner
| abc1.jpg
| abc2.jpg
| abc3.jpg

Double checked settings display with responsive image and style selected, run cron, flush cache, and run update, recreated image styles with no success. Would appreciate any pointers before I give up on the Responsive Images.

Thanks much.

Comment: If this was me, I would just create a new image style and see if that one works. If it does, replace it with the broken one.

Comment: Thanks Ryan. I did that, but no luck. Still get the same output slider_mobile1 | ---public | ---core | ---modules | ---image | sample.png .   The original image does not have a the jpg?itok=dWUQHvWx appended to it, just abc.jpg, so it never gets created in the first place.